# Yii2 Active Record result in controller

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have a very trivial (not for me) probleme in Yii2 with the ActiveRecord class. 
I fetchd data (all of them) in the controller and i need the result right there. Is there any solution to do this?

Thank you for Your answers!

Gábor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example:

```
$users=User::find()->all();
```

Now, you can loop through users like below:

```
foreach($users as $user):
    echo $user->id;
    //or do anything else here
endforeach;
```

To be more familiar with Active Record I would suggest you to take a look at [**official document**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data).